# SAS search for value of variable

Tags: search, sas, algebra

I am relatively new to SAS with limited programming experience.  I need to write code that searches for the value of a specific variable that will form an equality.  For example, I need to find the value of k that makes the following algebraic equation hold:

A = B + {[(C - k(B)] / (1+k)} + {[(D - k(E)] / (1+k)^2}, etc.

In this equation, I know the values of A, B, C, D, etc. and need to search for a value of k (the discount rate) that fits the equality.

Here's the proc model code I'm trying to use:

```
proc model data = test noprint;
p = bv0 + ((e1 - (k * bv0)) / (1+k)) + ((e2 - (k * bv1)) / ((1+k)**2)) + ((e3 - (k * bv2)) / ((1+k)**3)) + ((e3 - k *(bv2)) * (1+g)) / (((1+k)**3) * (k - g));
ENDOGENOUS k;
solve k / out = est;
run;
```

When I run this code, I receive the following error message:

WARNING: No equations are defined in the model. (Check for missing VAR or ENDOGENOUS statement.)
ERROR: The following solve variables do not appear in any of the equations to be solved: k

Any help anyone can provide would be great!  Thanks!

Comment: k(B), k(E) and k are the same?

Comment: Yes, all the same k - the value I need find.  I attempted to use proc model but I'm immediately receiving error messages

Comment: Post `proc model` code and error.

Comment: I updated the post to include the code and the error message.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `p` is supposed to be the name of an equation, try adding `eq.` prefix before `p`. If `p` is a variable that the expression on the right should be equal to, then replace `p` with `eq.equation1` and put `-p` on the right side.